# Get html items from view to control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Still kind of new to MVC, so please bear with me. I'm trying to grab some dynamically generated HTML. In this case, list items in my notifyList. I plan on looping through each one in the controller and adding them as database entries. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

View

```
@model _BaseViewModel

// The form it's within...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Leaf", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm" }))

<div class="editor-label bottom-area bottom-header">
    Notification List:
</div>
<div class="editor-field bottom-area">
    <ul id="notifyList"></ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(_BaseViewModel model)
{
    // Some loop here
       // get html here
    db.UserItems.AddObject(model.user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    //

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: How are the items generated? What does the ul contain? What do you want to fetch in the controller? How does the _BaseViewModel look like?

Comment: The ul doesn't contain anything. I'm using JQuery to append li to the ul. I want to fetch the li. My model, or at least what would pertain:

public Intra.Models.UserItem user { get; set; }

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you use jQuery to fetch `<li/>` elements into `notifyList`. What you need to do here is to generate a hidden input as well. Sample:

```
$("#btnAppend").click(function() { 
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        var _val = "Foo " + i;
        var $li = $("<li/>").text(_val);
        var $hidden = #("<input/>").
            attr("type", "hidden")
            attr("name", "foo").
            val(_val);

        $hidden.appendTo($li);

        $li.appendTo("#notifyList");
    }
});
```

This code will generate following output inside your DOM:

```
<ul id="notifyList">
    <li>Foo 0<input type="hidden" value="Foo 0" name="foo" /></li>
    <li>Foo 1<input type="hidden" value="Foo 1" name="foo" /></li>
    <li>Foo 2<input type="hidden" value="Foo 2" name="foo" /></li>
    <li>Foo 3<input type="hidden" value="Foo 3" name="foo" /></li>
</ul>
```

When you make a http form post, you can grab the values by the below controller action implementation:

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] foo) { 

    foreach(var item in foo) { 
        //Work with each individual item
    }

    //continue your code
}
```

Comment: written it with notepad, hope there is no typo :s

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work this way. html only exists in the view. the controller has no concept of html (not should it). data sent to the controller comes in 1 of types (GET, POST). there are others, but these are the main to.

get is typically associated with the querystring `www.domain.com/mypage.aspx?key=value`
where post is the input values from form

```
<form action="mypage.aspx" method="post">
    <input name="key" value="value"/>
    <input type="submit" value="click me"/>
</form>
```

So adding items to a html list won't provide any meaning to the controller. javascript and ajax provide more options on how the data gets sent to the server, but the data is sent, not the markup. and the data is sent as key value pairs.